# Is it a good idea to have separate instances for the public API Server and API Server used by the Web App?

Tags: architecture, api, api-design, node.js, nginx

I've built a React Web application with an Express REST API server and Firebase Auth. Also, Nginx is set up as a reverse proxy, so API calls from React to `https://mydomain.com/api` are routed to backend `http://localhost:8002`.

Now I want to publish part of my APIs  under `https://api.mydomain.com` with an API Key scheme. I've modified the Express server so it can handle both auth schemes based on `Authorization` header (i.e. `Bearer` for Firebase, `ApiKey` for API Key).

The question is: Is it a good idea to have separate backend instances serving Web App and Public APIs (i.e. route `api.mydomain.com` to `localhost:8003` and `mydomain.com/api` to `localhost:8002`)? What benefits could it bring? Or should I direct API calls from the Web App to `api.mydomain.com` to keep setup simple?

One of the reasons I think is to apply different rate limiting for each endpoint.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you mean copies of the same api or a separate "backend for front end" api

Comment: @Ewan I mean several instances, like routing api.mydomain.com to localhost:8003 and my.domain.com/api to localhost:8002

Comment: hmm well there are some reasons I can imagine you might do it, but if its the same endpoint (ie code underneath) then not sure what you would be trying to achieve